# How can I concatenate strings and numerics to make a table?

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I would like to make a table that contains the numeric values and concatenate those numeric values with the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a nice looking table like the one in your question, you are probably going to have to use [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML). You can look [at this as an example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14453) of how to format a table for publishing in MATLAB.

If you're data has some structure to it you can put it in a dataset array, and MATLAB will make it look nicer when you `disp()` it. See the post *[Printing Variables to HTML Tables in Published Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553691/display-matrix-with-row-and-column-labels/6557258#6557258)*.

Comment: Thanks. Both links are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot combine numbers and strings in same array. You can achieve your goal in multiple ways:

1) Use cell array -

```
 aq1 = { 'phi ','d[mm]','k[D] ','q[m/day] ','v[m/day] '; 1,2,3,4,5 };
 aq2  = { 'phi ','d[mm]','k[D] ','q[m/day] ','v[m/day] '; [1 2],[2 3; 4 5],3,4,5 };
```

2) Use struct - In this case you cannot assign brackets and slashes:

```
aq1 = struct('phi',1,'dmm',2,'kd',3,'qm',4,'v',6);
aq2 = struct('phi',[1 2 3],'dmm',[2 6 ; 7 0],'kd',zeros(7,8),'qm',4,'v',6);
```

3) Use Map:

```
aq1 = containers.Map('KeyType','char','ValueType','double');
aq1('phi') = 1
aq1('d[mm]') = 2
aq1('k[D]') = 3

aq2 = containers.Map('KeyType','char','ValueType','any');
aq2('phi') = [1 2 3]
aq2('d[mm]') = [4 5 ; 6 8];
aq2('k[D]') = 3
```

Comment: How can I include a vector for each string instead of a single scalar value?