# How to use tables in older versions of Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

Is there any function in MATLAB 2010 or below versions to print a result (eg: Some matrices) in tabular form? All I got from googling was a `table()` function that works only in MATLAB 2013 or above versions. I've got MATLAB 2010 in my machine and it's not practical to download a newer version as it is very large and I'm in a hurry. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Matlab versions 2012 and below,

can use printmat

```
printmat(yourMatrix, 'yourMatrix', 'ROW1 ROW2 ROW3 ROW4 ROW5', 'COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4 COLUMN5' );
```

or use

```
dataset({yourMatrix 'COLUMN1','COLUMN2','COLUMN3','COLUMN4','COLUMN5'}, ...
                'obsnames', {'ROW1','ROW2','ROW3','ROW4','ROW5'})
```

with reference: [Display matrix with row and column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553691/display-matrix-with-row-and-column-labels)

For Matlab versions 2012 and greater:

Use [array2table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html#btx3z8_-2_1), which converts an array into a table.

Example:

```
A = [1 4 7; 2 5 8; 3 6 9];

T = array2table(A)

T = 

    A1    A2    A3
    __    __    __

    1     4     7 
    2     5     8 
    3     6     9
```

Comment: .. the OP explicitly asked for a solution for prior Matlab versions. Tables were introduced in 2012 (sooner or later).

Answer (score 3):

How about using `displaytable` from Matlab File Exchange: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33717-display-formatted-text-table-of-data

Here's an example lifted from the documentation:

**Example 1 - Basic usage**

```
colheadings = {'number of projects','sales','profit'};
rowheadings = {'Jimmy Slick', 'Norman Noob'}
data = [3 rand(1) rand(1); 1 rand(1) rand(1)];
```

To format the first number in each row as a decimal (%d), the second
number %16.4f, and the third as %16.5E do the following:

```
wid = 16;
fms = {'d','.4f','.5E'};
```

In this case 16 will be the field width, and '.5E' is what to use for the
fms argument

```
fileID = 1;

displaytable(data,colheadings,wid,fms,rowheadings,fileID);
```

This is the formatted output:

```
            |number of projec |           sales |          profit 
Jimmy Slick |               3 |          0.4502 |    5.22908E-001 
Norman Noob |               1 |          0.9972 |    2.78606E-002
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am not sure if thats the function you meant with `table()`. What I am using is:

```
uitable('Data', c_Output(2:end,2:end), 'ColumnName', c_Output(1,2:end),...
         'RowName', c_Output(2:end,1), 'Units', 'normalized',...
         'Position', [0.575 0.32 0.33 0.13]);
```

c_Output is a matrix which contains my data and row/col names. The position is counted from the bottom left corner. So Top right would be (1,1). You would have to adjust it for each graph/position manually. Don't know if there is a build in function that converts a table to a "plot"